# Munin reading apache graph

Tags: munin, graph

Do I understand / read Munin apache Graph correct that today aroung lunch (12:00)

- 9 Clients visited apache +- 50 processes were running at this time and the load was around 50K / s?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, read the legend of your graph's:

In the first graph the horizontal axis (X-axis) is time and the vertical (Y-axis) represents the "accesses per second". In the bottom of the graph is a table with the averages, lowest and highest values of the counters in the graph.

That means that at the busiest moment apache handled 9 (9,56) requests per second. The number 9 does not relate to unique visitors. If you have a HTML page that references for example two CSS style sheets, 3 java-script files and three different images a visitor requesting that page will generate 9 individual "hits", 9 requests to your webserver. If those files are small and both your server and the visitor have enough bandwidth they can be completed in a single second, resulting in 9 accesses / second...

The second has the number of active, idle and spare servers. At the red circle it is a bit difficult to estimate but at most 35-40 apache instances were running, some actively processing requests and some idle.

Load is not quite the correct word for the third graph as it deals with the amount of network traffic (bytes/second) apache generates. 50 kilobyte per second (49,76 to be exact) at the peak.

Comment: Thanks for this broad and useful answer. Just a small question: which graph would I look at regarding max_clients settings in apache config. Apache processes (second graph)?

Comment: According to the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) "For non-threaded servers (i.e., prefork), MaxClients translates into the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to serve requests. The default value is 256..." which indeed corresponds to the number represented in your second graph.